# Appending HTML code to a div using JS - without double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to grab each photo from a directory, wrap it in some s and add the whole thing to a container div.

The issue is that in the browser each line shows up inside a set of double quotes.

Here a minimal version of my JS

```
<script>
var folder = "gallery-all/";
var photosRow = document.getElementById("photo-row");

var prefix = "<img src='";
var postfix = "'>";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                photosRow.append(prefix + folder + val + postfix);
            } 
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

This is what shows is the browser:

```
<img src='gallery-all/img1.jpg'>
<img src='gallery-all/img2.jpg'>
<img src='gallery-all/img3.jpg'>
<img src='gallery-all/img4.jpg'>
```

and upon inspecting the page the code is:

```
"<img src='gallery-all/img1.jpg'>"
"<img src='gallery-all/img2.jpg'>"
"<img src='gallery-all/img3.jpg'>"
"<img src='gallery-all/img4.jpg'>"
```

I have tried various methods of escaping, storing different parts as variables, etc. Regardless of what I do, the double quotes always show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only appending the string. You need actually append an element instead.

```js
<script>
var folder = "gallery-all/";
var photosRow = document.getElementById("photo-row");

var prefix = "<img src='";
var postfix = "'>";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
                const img = $('<img />', { src: folder + val });
                photosRow.append(img);
            } 
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue is

```
photosRow.append
```

If i replace this with

```
$('#photo-row')
```

then it works!

```
<script>
var folder = "gallery-all/";

var prefix = "<img src='";
var postfix = "'>";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                $('#photo-row').append(prefix + folder + val + postfix);
            } 
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

I do not have any idea why, though.

Comment: var photosRow = document.getElementById("photo-row");

get you javascript object, not Jquery object, and append  what you were using is this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append 
it needs an html element , but when you used $('#photo-row') it returns Jquery object and append method now the jquery method which builds element from text  
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp

Answer (score 0):

try to use the $() method to create an element from the text then append the element not the text 
as an example to create an image element and append it to container

```
container = $('#container');
imgEl = $('<img/>');
container.append(imgEl);
```

so your code will be

```
$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                photosRow.append($(prefix + folder + val + postfix));
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

*update*

```
var photosRow = document.getElementById("photo-row");
```

get you pure javascript object, not Jquery object, and append what you were using is this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append it needs an HTML element.

but when you used `$('#photo-row')` it returns Jquery object and append method now the jquery method which builds element from text https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp

don't mix between pure javascript and Jquery when you user Jquery stick to it